# using django.setup() from a subdirectory, how to reference settings?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a folder outside of my django app that I want to use to pull some data from django to use in some external scripts.

However when i run setup i get the below error:

```
[root@localhost cronjobs]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "infternal.settings")
'infternal.settings'
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> import django
>>> django.setup()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 22, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportE
```

How to I reference the settings module outside of the django folder?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I have multiple external scripts which use information from the django DB and from functions i already have in django, i run these scripts with cron periodically.

i wanted to move these scripts out of the root of my django app into a subdirectory and run them from there, but now i cant import settings.

old structure:

```
APP
-Site
-Site
-APP
--settings.py
manage.py
script.py
```

script runs fine here

new structure:

```
APP
-Cronjobs
--script.py
-Site
-Site
-APP
--settings.py
manage.py
```

script can no longer find infternal.settings

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achieve? Is the external script should run django? Using the DB as the bridge is not a good solution ? Writing a custom command ?

Comment: @OrDuan ive added more details, if they help?

Comment: Can you import infternal.settings?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this function, that i use commonly to run script from outside django.

```
def __setup_django(root_path, settings):
    import os
    import django

    os.chdir(root_path)

    # Django settings
    sys.path.append(root_path)
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = settings

    django.setup()

PROJECT_PATH = "/home/a/b/c/someproject"
PROJECT_SETTING = "someproject.settings.local"

__setup_django(PROJECT_PATH, PROJECT_SETTING)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set `PYTHONPATH` when you run your script.

```
PYTHONPATH=/app DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=app.settings /script.py
```

`PYTHONPATH` is akin to `PATH`, a colon delimited list of directories python uses to import modules.